# Spring Integration Kafka vs Spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-kafka

We are trying to implement a message channel between a worker spring application and a consumer spring application (there will be replicas of the same consumer on multiple JVMs)

With the Java Config there is limited documentation for the spring integration and I was able to find a documentation for the spring Kafka.I am not exactly sure how the dependency is working,

1. Is spring Kafka integration is based on Spring Kafka. Please give an idea on this?
2. Where can I find proper documentation for the new Release of Spring Integration Kafka?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Integration Kafka 2.0 is built on top of Spring Kafka (Spring Integration Kafka 1.x used the 0.8.x.x scala client directly).

The documentation for Spring Integration Kafka is in [Chapter 6 of the Spring Kafka Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#spring-integration).

At some point, it is likely that spring-integration-kafka will be pulled into the main spring integration project/documentation.

Comment: So in 2020, do we use spring-integration-kafka or spring-kafka? or does it vary by use case. we're replacing activemq with kafka

Comment: It depends on the use case - I updated the link to the current documentation.

Comment: Update: spring-integration is now a formal module of spring integration and its documentation is now there: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/