# Spring integration with Kafka

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

For Spring integration with Kafka, I notice there are 2 different artifacts available in maven repository as below

1. **spring-kafka**
2. **spring-integration-kafka**

I would like to understand what's the difference between the 2 artifacts and which one should i opt for ?

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866357/spring-integration-kafka-vs-spring-kafka

Comment: Thanks @abaghel That answered my doubt